# Android_Can't play the mp4 file generated by MediaMuxer

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

I am trying to use [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) and [MediaMux](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) to generate mp4 file. The code I am using is [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt).

I get some mp4 file. However, I can't play it with my player, which is just a normal software.

Does anyone has any idea? What should I do next?

Comment: Check the logcat output, especially at the point where `MediaMuxer#stop()` is called.  You should see some messages about how many frames it output and so on.  If you don't, it's possible `MediaMuxer` isn't getting a chance to put the finishing touches on the file, which would render it unreadable.

Comment: Yeah...  I guess that is the reason. I've checked the logcat. For the Frame NUM 14 and before, there is "sent xxx bytes to muxer". However, there is an error after NUM 14 "12-16 16:04:40.453: E/ACodec(4253): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.H264E] ERROR(0x80001005)
12-16 16:04:40.453: E/MediaCodec(4253): Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001005, internalError -2147483648)". And there is definitely no stuff like stop. So I guess the MediaMuxer didn't have the chance to do the finishing job.

Comment: @BrendonTsai Just wondering if you got this working. I am having the same exact issue and would appreciate your update :) Thanks.

Comment: @fadden Just wondering if you got this working. I am having the same exact issue and would appreciate your update :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue - in my case I simply wasn't calling muxer.stop() and ended up with a large unplayable file.